# ad not getting displayed inside table content

Tags: javascript, jquery, adsense

I am showing a bubble pop up whose contents is a table ,  in which i want to show google adsense ad ,

i am setting contents of a pop up ,by calling setBubblePopup method, 
as follows,

```
#(some element).setBubblePopup('<table> ...  </table>');
```

note that above content is inline , so i am removing  space but ';' is there ,
when i setting contents of a td element as adsense script content , it's not able not show the ad ( again , i have to make that inline )

Second test i did was ,  copy pasted the table content and directly tried running in normal html page, then i can see the ad,

Do  i need to encode , new lines also for setting adsense contents in the table ?

Comment: just an update, so here in this case, i am setting java script content to some div element after my page get's loaded , so may be that's the reason why script is not getting the ad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot dynamically insert move or create a Google adsense ad without causing invalid impressions which can lead to the Google account being used being banned from Google adsense. Adsense ads must be created where they belong while the page is being loaded using the script provided by Google (which only works before the `DOMContentLoaded` event is triggered)

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, you are correct , also it's against the policy of google to place ads in google pop up,   Thanks for the reply :)